# IntelliJ Moving a Subversion Repo

Tags: intellij-idea

I have spent too much time trying to get a subversion directory on one site to change to another using IntelliJ.

How am I supposed to transfer a subversion directory and take care of those .svn folders.  Every time I create a new project with new a repo and copy old source it gives me hell that commit from different working copies not allowed!

EDIT:

My current procedure:

Delete version control setting in preferences.

(Now there is no VCS)

VCS -> Import into Version Control

I procede from there with the new repo.

But when I am done **the old repo** is still in control.

Comment: This sounds a little bit less like an IntelliJ problem and more like an SVN problem...

Comment: Its totally IntellJ, my repo is fine.  How do I transfer repos from within intellij without moving project.  It keeps remembering credentials from my old repo even after deleting everywhere in intelliJ.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Cannot make it any clearer.  I am trying to transfer to another repo yet intelliJ keeps the old repo in control.

Comment: I agree with @Makoto.  You can upgrade to the latest SVN client.  Then it'll just have one .svn folder at the root.  It'll be way easier to copy sub directories.

Comment: There is a reason for rules here.  If you believe you have an answer than go for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ does not seem to properly support transferring VCS created with SVN 1.6.  Use this command to erase all traces of .svn subfolders in your project directory then try again.

```
find . -iname ".svn" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r
```